# Integrating constant variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration, numerical-integration

I want to iterate an integral of the form

```
integral(f,-1,1)
```

where `f = @(t) (s-t)*t`, with `s` being some variable, with respect to which I'm not integrating (so that I'm getting a function of s as a result of integration).

So I defined s as `syms s`, but I'm getting the following response:

> Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
>   Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.
>
> Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
>                   finalInputChecks(x,fx);
>
> Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
>               [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);
>
> Error in integralCalc (line 75)
>           [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);
>
> Error in integral (line 88)
>   Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

What can I do in order to integrate, say, s*dt from 0 to 1 and get s instead of errors in MATLAB?

Comment: `integral` is numerical and needs all variables defined as either a value or, in the case of (anonymous) functions, arguments.  You want to use `int` to integrate symbolically, I imagine.

Comment: Matlab says it has no such function as int.

Comment: Check if you have symbolic math toolbox which includes int(f): https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/integration.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com